# retrieve the document in sharepoint library when retrieving other data it has to retrieve the document also and how to search inside the document

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, share

I am created document library in sharepoint online and i am uploaded data and document successfully but i have a problem when i am retrieving that datas, data is perfectly retrieving but  document file retrieving from the sp.
PLEASE see the code how i am retrieved the data 
and how to retrieve the document
here i am use to retrieving the qualification when i am retrieving qualification it has to show all the data in the row document also but document is not displaying

And how to search document data using client side program.for example i am typing resume if any document inside resume data is having it has to highlight that and retrieve the file

what i have to do please help me

using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

using Microsoft.IdentityModel.S2S.Tokens;
using ClientOM = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using System.Text;
using candidate_profileWeb.Pages;

namespace candidate_profileWeb
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

```
    SharePointContextToken contextToken;
    string accessToken;
    Uri sharepointUrl;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string contextTokenString = TokenHelper.GetContextTokenFromRequest(Request);
        if (contextTokenString != null)
        {
            contextToken =
                TokenHelper.ReadAndValidateContextToken(contextTokenString, Request.Url.Authority);
            sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
            accessToken =
                TokenHelper.GetAccessToken(contextToken, sharepointUrl.Authority).AccessToken;


            Submit.CommandArgument = accessToken;
            retrive.CommandArgument = accessToken;

        }
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        }

        //Execute a request to add a list that has the user-supplied name.
    }


    protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var accesssToken = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;

        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        }

        //Execute a request to add a list that has the user-supplied name.
        ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accesssToken);
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection lists = web.Lists;
        List List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list name");
         clientContext.Load(List);

         DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;

        ListItemCreationInformation listCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();


        List documentsList = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list name");

        var fileCreationInformation = new FileCreationInformation();
        byte[] documentstream = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(browse.PostedFile.FileName);
        fileCreationInformation.Content = documentstream;
        fileCreationInformation.Url = browse.PostedFile.FileName;
        fileCreationInformation.Overwrite = true;
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadFile = documentsList.RootFolder.Files.Add(
           fileCreationInformation);



        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["cname"] = cname.Text;
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["qualification"] = qualification.Text;
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["gender"] = gender.Text;
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["address"] = address.Text;
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["posting"] = posting.Text;
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["domain"] = domain.Text;
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["experience"] = experience.Text;
        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields["salary"] = salary.Text;



        uploadFile.ListItemAllFields.Update();
        clientContext.Load(documentsList);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();


        try
        {
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception j)
        {
            Label2.Text = j.Message;


        }
    }





    protected void retrive_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var accesssToken = ((Button)sender).CommandArgument;
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            sharepointUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);
        }


        ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(sharepointUrl.ToString(), accesssToken);
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        ListCollection lists = web.Lists;
        List List = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("list name");
        clientContext.Load(List);
```

//here i am giving qualification data in the text box

```
        CamlQuery camlQuery = new CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.ViewXml = "<View><Query><Where><Eq>" +
             "<FieldRef Name ='qualification'/> <Value Type ='Text'>" + TextBox1.Text + "</Value>" +

             "</Eq></Where></Query></View>";
```

//{ "here i have to retrieve more than one data so i will use [AND] command to retrieve data but how to use [And] i don't know please help me " }

```
        Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection items = List.GetItems(camlQuery);
        clientContext.Load(items);
        try
        {
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception er)
        {
            Label1.Text = er.Message;
        }

        foreach (Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem item in items)
        {



            TableRow tablerow = new TableRow();
            TableCell tablecell1 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell2 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell3 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell4 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell5 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell6 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell7 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell8 = new TableCell();
            TableCell tablecell9 = new TableCell();

            tablecell1.Text = item.FieldValues["cname"].ToString();
            tablecell2.Text = item.FieldValues["qualification"].ToString();
            tablecell3.Text = item.FieldValues["gender"].ToString();
            tablecell4.Text = item.FieldValues["address"].ToString();
            tablecell5.Text = item.FieldValues["posting"].ToString();
            tablecell6.Text = item.FieldValues["domain"].ToString();
            tablecell7.Text = item.FieldValues["experience"].ToString();
            tablecell8.Text = item.FieldValues["salary"].ToString();
         tablecell9.Text = item.FieldValues["document"].ToString();
```

// //here i have to retrieve file document.how to change it byte type and how it show i don't know here what i have to do

tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell1);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell2);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell3);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell4);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell5);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell6);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell7);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell8);
                    tablerow.Cells.Add(tablecell9);
                    ListTable.Rows.Add(tablerow);

```
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your exact question is. But regarding your second question about how to search.

This article explains how you can use SharePoint (Online) search in a client application by using CSOM

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Query-Search-with-the-649f1bc1